# Integral $\int \frac{dx}{\tan x + \cot x + \csc x + \sec x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{\tan x + \cot x + \csc x + \sec x}$$
$$\tan x + \cot x + \csc x + \sec x=\frac{\sin x + 1}{\cos x} +\frac{\cos x + 1}{\sin x} $$
$$= \frac{\sin x +\cos x +1}{\sin x \cos x}$$
$$t= \tan {\frac{x}{2}}$$
On solving ,
$$\frac{1}{\tan x + \cot x + \csc x + \sec x}=\frac{t(1- t)}{1+ t^2}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{\tan {\frac{x}{2}}(1-\tan {\frac{x}{2}})}{1+\tan^2 {\frac{x}{2}}}{dx}$$

I think, I have made the things more difficult. How can I proceed further? Is there any better substitution for it?

Comment: $x=2\arctan(z)$ and everything becomes elementary

Comment: You can multiply and divide by $\csc x \sec x$. After that use your substitution $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ will take you through.

Comment: @tired It will increase the denominator and this will be difficult to integrate $$\frac{2z(1-z)}{(1+z^2)^2}{dz}$$

Comment: @AakashKumar This is asking for partial fractions decomposition. Your denom is already factored. Tedious but doable. Set up: $\frac{Ax+B}{1+z^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{(1+z^2)^2}$

Comment: @AakashKumar where exactly do you see the difficulties?

Comment: @imranfat pfd is not necessary. just notice that $\partial_z\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)=\frac{2z}{(1+z^2)^2}$

Comment: @tired I didn't catch that, I straight away went with the "sledge hammer" method. But the point I was trying to make to the OP is that these kind of fractional terms normally ought to be done with PFD. Is he able to do that? And hence your question to him regarding the "difficulties" is valid.

Comment: @tired. By the way, what's up with that cat???

Comment: @imranfat it is just tired i guess ;)

Comment: One could also simplify the integrand to $(\cos x+\sin x-1)/2$. Then it is _really_ easy to integrate.

Comment: @mickep Thanks, it really made it easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{\tan x + \cot x + \csc x + \sec x}=$

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1+\sin x+\cos x}\,dx=\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{1+\sin x+\cos x}\cdot\frac{1-(\sin x+\cos x)}{1-(\sin x+\cos x)}\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int\frac{\sin x\cos x(1-(\sin x+\cos x))}{1-(\sin x+\cos x)^2}\,dx=\int\frac{\sin x\cos x-\sin^2 x\cos x-\cos^2x\sin x}{-2\sin x\cos x}\,dx$

$\displaystyle=-\frac{1}{2}\int(1-\sin x-\cos x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}(-x-\cos x+\sin x)+C$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{aligned}\int \frac{1}{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\:+\:\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\:+\:\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\:+\:\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}dx
& = \int \:\frac{\sin \:\left(2x\right)}{2\left(\cos \:\left(x\right)+\sin \:\left(x\right)+1\right)}dx
\\& =\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int \:\frac{\sin \left(2x\right)}{\cos \left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)+1}dx
\\& =\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int \:\frac{\sin \left(t\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+1}dt
\\& =\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int \:\sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-1dt
\\& =\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}\left(-2x+2\sin \left(x\right)-2\cos \left(x\right)\right)+C}
\end{aligned}$$

Applyied substitution: $$\color{blue}{t=2x,\quad \:dt=2dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

A trigonometric formula can be used：
\begin{align}
&(\sin x+\cos x+1)(\sin x+\cos x-1)=\sin 2x\\
I&=\int\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x+1}dx=\int\frac{1}{2}(\sin x+\cos x-1)dx=\frac{1}{2}(-\cos x+\sin x-x)+C\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}\int \frac{d x}{\tan x+\cot x+\csc x+\sec x}&=\int \frac{\cos x \sin x}{1+\cos x+\sin x} d x \\&= -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1-(\cos x+\sin x)^2}{1+\cos x+\sin x} d x \\& = -\frac{1}{2} \int(1-\cos x-\sin x) d x\\&= \frac{1}{2}(-x+\sin x-\cos x)+C\end{aligned}  $$